# NextJS - Error: Cannot find module '/<path>/.next/fallback-build-manifest.json' in next.config.js file

Tags: reactjs, pdf, webpack, next.js

When adding custom webpack configurations to the `next.config.js` file for the NextJS I am able to compile fine, except for when adding configurations for `plugins` for webpack.

plugin configuration for webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {

   ... config code ...

    config.plugins = [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
        process: "process/browser",
      }),
    ];

   ... config code ...

    return config;
  },
};
```

When uncommenting specifically the plugin lines, webpack compilation is successful. But as stated from a npm package, that line is needed for usage.

Configuration setup [here](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf#readme)

Otherwise the resulting error would be `Error: Cannot find module /<path>/.next/fallback-build-manifest.json`

Where usually there would be a produced build manifest for the `.next` folder.

Comment: Encountering a similar issue after invalid hook react error... which was related to webpack config... have you find any leads on this issue?